# How to add user-registration form to my django app?

Tags: django, authentication, authorization, django-1.9

I have been able to create a form where the user can input their username and password following this [tutorial](https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial-extensions/blob/master/authentication_authorization/README.md).

I want to be able to create a user account by: pressing a button  which will transfer the user to another page where they will fill out a form and the details are saved onto a database. I also want to make sure that no username is repeated. However, I don't know how to code it. I am very new to django hence why I am struggling.

I am using windows and atom code editor if that makes a difference. Please can someone help me code it.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UEY0ZIQ9dU&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=34), it really helped me and if you follow it completely you'll by more familiar with the django configuration.

**Update**

Also, you can follow this steps:

- 1.- Create a forms.py file inside your app directory with the following code

  ```
  # we import the django default user model
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  # also, import the forms to create em
  from django import forms

  # define a class for your form, it can be anithing you want
  class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
      # password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
      # this Meta class is the way we send information for our form
      class Meta:
          # define the model
          model = User
          # define the fields you need (note that username and password are required)
          fields = [
              'password',
              'username',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'is_staff',
              'email',
          ]
          # then, in widgets you can define the input type of the field and give
          # attributes to each one
          widgets = {
              'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}),
              'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username', 'placeholder': 'username'}),
              'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'first_name', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
              'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'last_name', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
              'is_staff': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'is_staff'}),
              'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'email', 'placeholder': 'email'}),
          }
  ```
- 2.- Then you have to create the view.py file inside the app directory (if not created)

  ```
      # import the View form django and the UserForm we created on step 1
      from django.views.generic import View
      from .forms import UserForm
      # And some other things we need
      from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
      from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
      from django.contrib.auth.models import User # we also need this one
      from django.shortcuts import render
      from django.contrib import messages
      from django.views import generic

  # create the class view, named as you need
  class UserFormView(View):
      # define the form to use, in this case the form we created
      form_class = UserForm
      # define the template_name, your main html file wher your are goin to use the form
      template_name = 'usersControll/add.html'
      # and the reverse_lazy is helpfull when the user succesfully added a new user
      # replace 'users-add' with the name of your rute 
      success_url = reverse_lazy('users-add')

      def get(self, request):
          form = self.form_class(None)
          return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

      def post(self, request):
          form = self.form_class(request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():
              return self.form_valid(form)
          else:
              return self.form_invalid(form, request)

      def form_valid(self, form):
          # when the info the user gave us is valid, stop the commit 
          # so we can give some nice format to this info
          user = form.save(commit=False)
          # the "form.cleaned_data" help us to give a standar format to the info
          username = form.cleaned_data['username']
          first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
          last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
          password = 'tempPass'
          user.set_password(password)
          # aaand we save it to the database
          user.save()

          # in my case a send a succesfull massage to the user indicating that
          # went fine
          messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, "El usuario <b>form.cleaned_data['first_name']</b> fue registrado exitosamente.")
          return super(UserFormView, self).form_valid(form)

      def form_invalid(self, form, request):
          return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
  ```

  - 3.- Add the route in your urls.py file

    ```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^add/', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='users-add'),
        # dont forget to add the .as_view() because our view is a class and not a function
    ]
    ```
- 4.- finally just add the form in your html file

  ```
  <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{msg.level_tag}} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                {% autoescape off %}
                  {{ msg.message }}
                {% endautoescape %}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}

          {% if form.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Oops, algo salió mal.
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="form-group {% if form.first_name.errors %} has-error {% endif %}">
              <label class="control-label" for="first_name">Nombre</label>
              {{ form.first_name }}
              <p class="help-block">{{ form.first_name.errors.as_text }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {% if form.last_name.errors %} has-error {% endif %}">
              <label class="control-label" for="last_name">Apellido</label>
              {{ form.last_name }}
              <p class="help-block">{{ form.last_name.errors.as_text }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {% if form.username.errors %} has-error {% endif %}">
              <label class="control-label" for="username">Nombre de Usuario</label>
              {{ form.username }}
              <p class="help-block">{{ form.username.errors.as_text }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {% if form.email.errors %} has-error {% endif %}">
              <label class="control-label" for="email">Correo Electronico</label>
              {{ form.email }}
              <p class="help-block">{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {% if form.is_staff.errors %} has-error {% endif %}">
              <label class="control-label" for="is_staff">Administrador</label>
              {{ form.is_staff }}
              <p class="help-block">{{ form.is_staff.errors.as_text }}</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div> <!-- panel-body -->

        <div class="panel-footer">
          <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Registrar">
        </div> <!-- panel-footer -->
      </div> <!-- panel -->
    </form>
  ```

Hope this is usefull for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13749168)

Comment: @techspider, thanx for the feedback, i'll edit the answer.